# How can I get the order of derivation of a symbolic expression?

Tags: differential-equations, polynomials, calculus-and-analysis

Given an expression like, say `a y''[x] + b y'[x] + c y[x]`, how can I process it to get the max order of differentiation ?

e.g. on the above example, this should return `2`. On

```
y'[x] + y[x]
```

This should return `1`.

Note: this should be adapted to fit cases of derivatives higher than 2 where Mathematica trades the primed notation `'` for the upper index in parenthesis notation `(i)`.

Comment: Take a look at `FullForm` of your expression and proceed with `Cases`.

Comment: You might also want to check out the option for `Cases` called `Heads`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following extracts the maximum derivative order using `Cases`

```
derviativeorder[expr_] := Max[0, Max[Cases[expr, Derivative[n_]->n, ∞, Heads->True]]]

derivativeorder /@ {y''[x] + b y'[x] + c y[x], y'[x] + y[x], y[3]}
(*{2, 1, 0}*)
```